# email link to php page on my site with a parameter

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send my customer a link to my payment gateway for a product configured offline.  I send the customer an email with a link such as

example.com/payme.php?n=123456

which works when I paste it to a browser but results in file not found when clicked from email link.  I know this is because of the parameter, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why is it because of the parameter?. If it works when you put it in the browser, I think your problem is just with the email itself.

Comment: A link is a link. No matter if it contains URL parameters or not. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: Yes I thought so too but when I click the email link it goes to my site and cant find the url and redirects to the home page but when I paste and go it works fine!

Comment: How does the link looks like in the e-mail? Maybe you can post it? Is the parameter missing? Does the e-mail contains plain text or HTML?

Comment: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1252; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Kelly

Please go to the following link to place the order

example.com/Portal.php?n=1516948 
<example.com/Portal.php?n=1516948 >

Comment: its directing to https but I cant post that here

Comment: Maybe its something in my server php config that is not set?  I am on a dedicated server not shared

Comment: a plain text email needs http:// at the beginning for most email clients to recognise it as a link.

Comment: it is prefixed with https:// but stack overflow does not allow me to paste it here in that format ..only as example.com/..blah blah